# Riddle of something (mildly) gross

Tags: riddle

> I am white.
>   I am put in a room which is small.
>   My brothers live with me in those rooms.
>   Sometimes, someone gives me yellow drinks or brown food.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **the WC (or toilet)**

Explanation:

> It is white and is being putted in a smaller room than the others. He has some "brothers" like bidet, sink and so on and people use it to.. piss and poop (yellow drink and brown food).

Comment: What should I do? Can I accept 2 answers?

Comment: @劉昀LAUWAN No, only one can be accepted, you should choose thinking about the completeness of the answer

Comment: @劉昀LAUWAN Your choice :) See this : https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3267/is-first-answer-a-valid-reason-to-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 9):

Are you

> **teeth**?

Explanation

> Teeth are white.
>  They live in a small room (our mouth).
>  They live with 32 brothers. 
>  We eat brown food/yellow drinks via mouth i.e. feed teeth.

Comment: LOL, opposite ends of the same process! :-)

Comment: @Phylyp indeed :p

Comment: Looks more correct than toilet.

Comment: You don't need to use your teeth for drinks, yellow or otherwise.

Comment: @Randal'Thor they strike teeth though when we drink them(somewhat?)

Answer (score 6):

You are

> a toilet

I think no more explanation is needed

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> underwear/panties

I am white.

> Most are white

I am put in a room which is small.

> Nobody puts them in a big box

My brothers live with me in those rooms.

> All the other clean underwear/panties or socks

Sometimes, someone gives me yellow drinks or brown food.

> *Sometimes* you do mistakes and forget things...

Comment: Panties could be correct answer if there would be only white panties and panties should be feminine.

Comment: @TheExorcist I added also underwear .

Comment: Now it could be partial match although hypothetically if there exist a engine which could measure the accuracy or closeness of riddle answer  then this answer would be last of stack.